# How do I get base64.default to work in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not familiar with Java.

```
return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

On DEFAULT, I'm getting "DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field"

I got the code block from a site that noted, "The java code below uses a base64 util class from android SDK but you can replace it like with one from apache commons", which I'm pretty sure is the issue, that missing util class.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/codec/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.java?view=markup

So I clicked on that and got there and... O.o

I see a wall of code with no context on what to do with it. I need the code to match with C# code and give an identical result, so switching to another format isn't the solution. I think I'll have to impliment that util class, but I haven't the first clue what that actually entails.

Comment: Have you tried using `Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypt(plainTextbytes, keyBytes, keyBytes))` I believe that this is the apache equivalent of the android code you are using.

Comment: @AndrewCumming "The method encodeBase64String(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64"

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do with the wall of code: Since you're trying to use `encodeToString`, you search for `encodeToString` to see if there's a method with that name.  There isn't one, in this code.  But there might still be one in the class, if the class has a superclass that defines the method.  So you look to see if the class has a superclass, and it does:

```
public class Base64 extends BaseNCodec {
```

So now you have to try to find the code for `BaseNCodec`.  There isn't a hyperlink to it, but you can check the URL, look for `Base64`, and try replacing `Base64` with `BaseNCodec` to see if the URL follows the same format.  That works.  And that class **does** have `encodeToString`:

```
/**
 * Encodes a byte[] containing binary data, into a String containing characters in the Base-N alphabet.
 * Uses UTF8 encoding.
 *
 * @param pArray
 *            a byte array containing binary data
 * @return A String containing only Base-N character data
 */
public String encodeToString(final byte[] pArray) {
    return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(encode(pArray));
}
```

Don't worry about the body, just look at the javadoc and the parameters.  Unlike the Android version, there's only one parameter.  There's no "flags" parameter, and since on Android the flags parameter is a default, you can guess that the lack of a flags parameter isn't going to be a problem.  You should be able to make it work with just the `byte[]` parameter.

There's a problem, though: the Apache version isn't `static`, which means `Base64.encodeToString` won't work.  You need an actual instance of a `Base64`.  To figure out what you want, you'll need to go back to the `Base64` code and look at the constructors; then look at the Javadoc for each constructor, and figure out what you want.

It will also help to look at the Javadoc for Android.  Start at `http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html` and look for the `Base64` class.  You'll be able to find the `encodeToString` method there.  This takes a `flags` parameter, and although the method doesn't say much about the meaning of the flags, you can scroll up and see what different flags are available to you.  One is `URL_SAFE`.  Since the instructions told you to use `DEFAULT`, that means they **don't** want you to use the `URL_SAFE` option.  That's important, because some of the constructors in the Apache version give you options whether to use URL-safe encoding; don't, unless you decide that the above site is wrong.

I don't know what exact code you need to write.  But that should get you started and give you an idea of how you could research problems like this yourself in the future.

Comment: What's a constructor? I mean, my Java expertise is Googling for code to do what I want. I had to google to figure out that I couldn't use Visual Studio and had to download Eclipse. I'm lucky to be able to load my project. I feel like I'm missing some really major stuff, but since today is really the last day to finish this project, I'm just for quick and dirty right now.

Comment: `Base64 object = new Base64(...)` with whatever parameters you need.  That constructs an object.  However, if you have to complete a Java project today and you don't know the fundamentals of Java, I wish you a ton of luck.

Comment: It's an information security project. I was just doing part of it in Java so I could run it on my Android. I suppose I could always just do it all in C# and say it was runnable on a windows phone, I just didn't happen to have one? Lol. I'm down to that one line of code, and have been for weeks. That's why I've stuck with it. Because I'm STUPIDLY close to finishing. If I could get that one line of code working, I'd have an A in the bag. Without it, I've got to redo the thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that you can use the Apache Commons Codec library to base64 encode the byte[] instead of the android library.

This is the docs for the class you linked: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

```
return Base64.encodeBase64( encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes) );
```

Comment: "The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64"

Answer (score 0):

Use `return  Base64.encodeBase64String(byte[]);`  from apache commons Base64 to return encryption as String and it will also resolve any padding issue between PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding.